# How to add individual product tax in magento?

Tags: magento

I have created a product attribute `Product Tax` and from the admin catalog I have entered 10% tax on one product.

Now on front side I want to apply 10% tax to the product price.
There are many function for getting price, which one should I be using?

Comment: Is solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to create a tax rule from sales > tax and then apply this tax class to product

Comment: Admin need input box for tax in each product.If i will create rule then is there any way admin insert amount of percentage?

Comment: no this is not possible you have to manage this trough sales > tax